# how to enable touchStart on touch screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am creating a web interface for touch based screens . everything is fine 
but I am having a problem with touchStart  event .
when i click the button the action starts , but i want the button to change color before it goes to the action . 
I tried to use many method but it doesn't work . 
 below are some of the methods i have used

```
 window.addEventListener('load', function(){ 

    document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
        alert(e.changedTouches[0].pageX) 
    }, false)
}, false)
```

and this

```
    $(document).bind('touchstart', function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "black"); 
});
```

and this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hover').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('hover_effect');
    });
});
```

but none of those methods worked .

any idea ?? is there anything missing in the library or something ?

Comment: No need for JS, use the CSS `:active` state

Comment: nop still nothing  is changing